# How to scan directory and then move files based on conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, operating-system, shutil, pathlib

Ideally, it'd scan through the downloads folder, find the files whose extensions are '.png' or '.jpg', then move those files to the pictures folder.
Here is my code:

```
import os 
import shutil
import pathlib
source_dir = r'C:\Users\zaner\Downloads'
target_dir = r'C:\Users\zaner\OneDrive\Pictures'    
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
extension = pathlib.Path(file_names).suffix

if extension == '.jpg' or '.png':
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_names), target_dir)
```

I have been attempting to pass each file name as a string through the if statement, but am unable to do so. I have been met with this error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
I have looked up solutions, but none seem to apply here/ are just confusing tbh

Comment: Sorry in advance for the formatting mistakes, please leave a comment if it is too jumbled, I'll try to help out.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
```

`file_names` Is a `List`. And, as the error states:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

your'e passingh in a list. Instead, you should pass in a `str`.

So, since it's a list, you'll need to iterate over it and move the files accordingly. Your refactored code can look something like this:

```py
import os
import shutil
import pathlib


source_dir = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads"
target_dir = r"C:\Users\zaner\OneDrive\Pictures"
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

for file_names in file_names:
    extension = pathlib.Path(file_names).suffix
    if extension == ".jpg" or extension == ".png":
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_names), target_dir)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still receiving the same error. Do you think it's more of a system issue?

Answer (score 0):

use backslash in your source_dir and target_dir or f-strings

```
import os 
import shutil
import pathlib
source_dir = r'C:\Users\zaner\Downloads'
target_dir = r'C:\Users\zaner\OneDrive\Pictures'
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
for file_name in file_names:
    extension = pathlib.Path(file_name).suffix
    if extension in [".jpg", ".png"]:
        shutil.copy(f'{source_dir}/{file_name}', f'{target_dir}/') # windows use \ f'{source_dir}\{file_name}', f'{target_dir}\'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately the backslashes lead to unterminated string literal errors. I'm sorry, and I have honestly thought about modyfying the linter to ignore this error lol

Comment: updated with f-strings

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path
import tqdm

source_dir = Path('C:\Users\zaner\Downloads')
target_dir = Path('C:\Users\zaner\OneDrive\Pictures')
img_paths = glob(str(source_dir / "*.png")) + glob(str(source_dir / "*.jpg"))

for img_path in tqdm(img_paths):
    shutil.move(img_path, (str(target_dir) + Path(img_path).name))
```

Haven't tested it and I'm sure there is a nicer way to combine the 2 glob statements or to sum it to one - but it should work